# How to read simple pseudo XML file?

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to read info from a simple, pseudo XML file I created to get the content. Here is what my XML file would look like :

```
<title>Form Title</title>

<Message1>A message or something</Message1>

<FormWidth>500</FormWidth>

<FormHeight>500</FormHeight>
```

The XML class I find online and inside Visual Studio are too advance. This is just a simple config file I'd like to use. Any tips?

Comment: You're making life unnecessarily hard. That "too advanced class" is well-documented and well-tested, with numerous examples on the internet. Just slap a `<config>...<</config>` wrapper on your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function like this to your code behind (I just converted this from c# so you may need to change some things):

```
Private Shared Function ReadValueFromXML(ValueToRead As String) As String
Try
    Dim doc As New XPathDocument(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("filenameOfYourXML.xml"))
    Dim nav As XPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator()
    Dim expr As XPathExpression
    expr = nav.Compile(Convert.ToString("/") & ValueToRead)
    Dim iterator As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(expr)
    While iterator.MoveNext()
        Return iterator.Current.Value
    End While
    Return String.Empty
Catch
    Return String.Empty
End Try
End Function
```

Don't forget to add these import statements in your code behind as well:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.XPath
```

And when you use it, let's say you want to get the value of FormWidth:

```
Dim FormWidth As String = ReadValueFromXML("FormWidth")
```